# How can a single form_for work for new, update and edit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In rails 3, is it possible to create a form_for that works for both new, update and edit actions?

If yes, how do I do this?

I have a admin section so my urls look like:

```
/admin/posts/ {new,update, edit}
```

Answer (score 30):

Just let `form_for` handle it:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for-label-Resource-oriented+style

controller:

```
class ControllerName
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end
  def edit
    @post = Post.find params[:id]
  end
end
```

view:

```
<%= form_for [:admin, @post] do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for a long time. Thanks man!

Answer (score 22):

Because new needs to be sent to create, and edit needs to be sent to update a single form_for will not work.. unless (which I don't necessarily recommend) you place a tertiary operator in the form_form params

```
form_for(@post, :url => (@post.new_record? ? admin_posts_url : admin_post_url(@post)))
```

Because in your new action you are going to have **Post.new** which creates an object with a nil id, and in your edit action you will have **Post.find(params[:id])**

Comment: Instead of `@post.id.nil?`, I would prefer `@post.new_record?`

Comment: I agree it feels too hacky so you don't recommend that. But how could we simulate the default form_for behaviour which will always be different when creating and when editing an object, without using resource and dedicated controller. There should be something like this `:url => {:create => {:action => '', :controller => ''}, :update => {:action => '', :controller => ''}}`, shouldn't it ?

Comment: Instead of `@post.new_record?`, I would prefer `@post.persisted?` http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-persisted-3F